# input string variable to class object variable python 3

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables, pygame

Hi my pygame is going good, but after i blit to screen a message box displaying Robot Name:
When they press the enter key
I get the name capitalized in a string variable called: new_robot1        (ex."Crusher")

I use new_robot1 to assign the robots name argument in the class init

AND i get a second string variable called: data_bot (ex. "crusher") BUT

I cant seem to find anywhere on stack how to use data_bot to create my class object

example code:  data_bot = Robot(all required params to init class) but doesnt
work because data_bot is a string type

people are talking about using a dictonary?

```
robot_dic = {}
robot_dic['data_bot':crusher]
robot_dic['data_bot'] = Robot(all required params to init class)?????
```

I am new to python, but I can't define key value: crusher at runtime...

as soon as i get both new_robot1, AND data_bot variables, I would like to run
a function like example code above.

Please show me the correct way to use dictionary for this problem

Comment: data_bot = "crusher"

Comment: new_bot1 = "Crusher"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable `data_bot` holds the key you want to store the `Robot` instance under in your dictionary, use `robot_dic[data_bot] = Robot(...)`. Note that there are no quotation marks around `data_bot` here, since we want the string stored in the variable of that name, not the string `"data_bot"` itself.

For more information, you may want to [read the Python Tutorial's chapter on Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), which includes a section introducing dictionaries and their syntax.

Comment: @ Blckknight ok just to answer your if question: data_bot holds the string "crusher", would it still work when creating the instance?  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

globals()[data_bot] = Robot(...)

After instance creation I tested: dir(), type, and called a pre-defined attribute of the class using the variable name crusher (for example) :)  All good.

Then I rename both used variables to "" after creation of class object
(program is ready to create another instant if ran again)
I'll just make sure to test so no overwriting is done in the future

If anyone sees any walls/Security issues I'll run into in the future can you please leave a comment?

I know I wont be using globals for anything else at the moment.
Thanks.